# How do you put programs on your desktop?

Tags: 14.04

Does anyone know how to put your programs that you've installed on your Desktop?

Comment: Are you seeking to put icon shortcuts to programs on your desktop as you might do in Windows?

Comment: Not all answers there work on 14.04, but some do. I'd suggest simply copying the .desktop file from `~/usr/share/applications` to your desktop, make it executable. That's all. (see link)

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer below by clicking the little grey check-mark below the numbers, turning it green...

Answer (score 2):

When running a program it has its icon on the left side (Unity Launcher),when you close the program it disappears,if you want to appear all the time right click on the icon while running a program and select lock to the launcher.

(It is valid only in Unity session)

Comment: The default is launcher on the left..