# So many user apps, but only a few on launcher, why not a launcher page or a command to install on launcher?

Tags: 14.04, launcher, directory, execute-command, installed-programs

I am new to Ubuntu, have v. 14.04. I look on installed apps page and see user apps installed but find no way to access them, and no way to place an app link in the launcher, why is this? People would get more use out of Ubuntu if there were an apps page showing all installed programs. Second it is difficult to find where the program is loaded, as in Windows they have a program directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "installed apps page"?

Comment: You can add installed programms to your launcher: http://askubuntu.com/a/224010/75166

Comment: Is this a question, disguised as a complaint or a complaint, disguised as a question?

Comment: @MadMike I mean something similar to Windows Program Files File which shows installed program folders.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm Try a complaint in the form of a question perhaps? Not trying to "disguise" anything. The complaint is I don't understand, the question is how? and/or why? The only way I saw of accomplishing what I wanted was to uninstall the program and reinstall it to get the icon in the launcher, a time wasting effort as I saw it. I have already tried one answer, and it satisfies me partly, I will continue to review other answers. Thank you

Comment: A simple question like: "how can I easily add icons to the launcher" would have given you a satisfying (reference to an-) answer within 2 minutes probably. Now people don't know how the question/complaint is meant.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is typical for people who have just migrated from Windows. You don't know names of all software packages yet, and it may be difficult to find out which app does what. Luckily there is a simple  solution:

**Install Classic Gnome Indicator.**

Open the terminal window by pressing Ctrl+AlT+T and write there:

```
sudo apt-get install classicmenu-indicator
```

Type in your password when asked.

If you prefer you may install it through Ubuntu software centre.

You can now see all the applications sorted by category through the indicator appearing on the right top part of the screen.

[image]

Read here for more info:   [Softpedia review for classic Gnome indicator](http://www.softpedia.com/reviews/linux/ClassicMenu-Indicator-Review-466198.shtml#sgal_2)

To learn to place an application link to the launcher see the link : [how to put programs on the desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562682/how-do-you-put-programs-on-your-desktop/562683#562683)
 It is easier than you think.

Comment: I just want to explain him in simple way. Please feel free to correct me if I am mistaken.  Ok I will remove the second part and leave the right to answer to more experienced people