# How to see all installed applications

Tags: search

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 default GUI, how can I see all the applications installed ? if I don't give a search keyword I can't see anything.

Comment: Ubuntu software center; option "installed"?

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for, but better than nothing. I had different kind of GUI before and there I had everything...

Comment: See the answer provided here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/574284/so-many-user-apps-but-only-a-few-on-launcher-why-not-a-launcher-page-or-a-comm/574439#574439

Answer (score 2):

In the terminal you can see a list of all installed packages like this:

`dpkg -l`

Or, for example, write listing to a file:

`dpkg -l > packages.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use terminal commands `dpkg --get-selections | less` or `dpkg --get-selections | grep packagename`